# rxFastTrees in Microsoft R: Parallel or Not?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, microsoft-r

I have a question about "parallelization" that the rxFastTrees() algorithm that is used in Microsoft R, here is a link to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/r-server/r-reference/microsoftml/rxfasttrees

This is clearly a boosting algorithm, and traditionally, boosting algorithms are not parallel in nature, but, there is an argument that you can set called trainThreads, I assume this means you can set the number of cores that you can use.

Does anyone know if there is a limit to the #of cores that can be used, and if this means that Microsoft's implementation is parallel?

Thanks.

Thomas

Comment: Hi Thomas, as far as I know; yes  - you can set the number of threads to use when training the model. I doubt you can set the number of threads to be greater than the number of cores you have on your box, (well, I guess you theoretically can set it to a greater number - but it would obvisouly not be able to utilize it). I do believe the MS implementation is parallell.

Comment: Hi @NielsBerglund great to know. Thanks!